# Summing and ordering at once

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table of orders. There I need to find out which 3 partner_id's have made the largest sum of amount_totals, and sort those 3 from biggest to smallest.

```
    testdb=# SELECT amount_total, partner_id FROM sale_order;
     amount_total | partner_id 
    --------------+------------
          1244.00 |          9
          3065.90 |         12
          3600.00 |          3
          2263.00 |         25
          3000.00 |         10
          3263.00 |          3
           123.00 |         25
          5400.00 |         12
    (8 rows)
```

Just starting SQL, I find it confusing ...

Comment: `amount_total` is a very unfortunate name for an amount that is obviously not total at all. Should be `amount` or something more descriptive. The aggregated amount can be `amount_total` or `amount_year` or whatever. Do you want to list the the aggregated amount or individual rows?

Comment: Also: What if 4 partners have the same total amount? Pick all 4? Pick 3? Define how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Aggregated amounts

If you want to list aggregated amounts, it can be as simple as:

```
SELECT partner_id, sum(amount_total) AS amout_suptertotal
FROM   sale_order
GROUP  BY 1
ORDER  BY 2 DESC
LIMIT  3;
```

The 1 in `GROUP  BY 1` is a numerical parameter, that refers to the position in the `SELECT` list. Just a notational shortcut for `GROUP  BY partner_id` in this case.

This ignores the special case where more than three partner would qualify and picks 3 arbitrarily (for lack of definition).

#### Individual amounts

```
SELECT partner_id, amount_total
FROM   sale_order
JOIN  (
   SELECT partner_id, rank() OVER (ORDER BY sum(amount) DESC) As rnk
   FROM   sale_order
   GROUP  BY 1
   ORDER  BY 2
   LIMIT  3
   ) top3 USING (partner_id)
ORDER  BY top3.rnk;
```

This one, on the other hand includes all peers if more than 3 partner qualify for the top 3. The [window function `rank()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-window.html) gives you that.

The technique here is to group by `partner_id` in the subquery `top3` and have the window function `rank()` attach ranks after the aggregation (window functions execute after aggregate functions).  `ORDER BY` is applied after window functions and `LIMIT` is applied last. All in one subquery.

Then I join the base table to this subquery, so that only the top dogs remain in the result and order by `rnk`.

Window functions require PostgreSQL 8.4 or later.

This is rather advanced stuff. You should start learning SQL with something simpler probably.

Answer (score 0):

```
select amount_total, partner_id
from (
    select
        sum(amount_total) amount_total,
        partner_id
    from sale_order
    group by partner_id
) s
order by amount_total desc
limit 3
```